# IEEEtran and glossaries-extra: glslink problems

Tags: glossaries, ieeetran, glossaries-extra

I am having troubles with getting `glossaries-extra` running when using `\glslink` command. For example when trying to compile

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex
% !BIB TS-program = bibtex
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{mathtools,xparse}

\usepackage[xindy,symbols,nomain]{glossaries-extra}
\makeglossaries

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\parens{\lparen}{\rparen}

\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={xxx}]{symb:pdf}{\ensuremath{ p\parens*{ aa | bb } }}

\NewDocumentCommand\pdf{moo}{%
    \glslink{symb:pdf}{p_{#3}\parens*{#1 \,\middle|\, #2}}%
}

\begin{document}
    asd
    \begin{align}
            \pdf{ a }[b][]
    \end{align}
    \printglossaries
\end{document}
```

I get the error message

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.11 \glsxtrnewsymbol
                     [description={xxx}]{symb:pdf}{\ensuremath{ p\parens*{ a...
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**Edit:**

Surprisingly, it works when adding `\gls{symb:pdf}` e.g. *before* `\begin{align}`. And it does not work when adding it after the first use `\pdf`. Why is that?

Comment: There seems to be a problem with `\glslink` (which I'll investigate). Try using `\glsdisp` instead. (I don't know why you're getting that undefined control sequence error. I can't reproduce that with your MWE.)

Comment: @NicolaTalbot I encountered similar error using MiKTeX on Windows. Simplified MWE added below.

Comment: This bug should now be fixed in version 1.35 (2018-08-13).

Answer (score 2):

The error persists in `glossaries-extra` v1.34 (MiKTeX + TeXstudio on Windows 10).

Simplified MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage[automake=true]{glossaries}
\usepackage[automake=true]{glossaries-extra}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{a}{
    name={name},
    description={desc}
}

\begin{document}

%   \glsdisp{a}{disp}
    \glslink{a}{link}

    \printglossaries

\end{document}
```

> **! Undefined control sequence.**
>   \glsxtrdiscardperiod #1#2#3->\glsxtrifwasfirstuse
>                                                     {\glsifattribute {#1}{reta...
>   l.15     \glslink{a}{link}

Changing `glossaries-extra` to `glossaries` or uncommenting `\glsdisp{a}{disp}` before `\glslink{a}{link}` causes the document to compile without errors.